# How to spin css cube each after each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two cubes.
I would like to spin them each after each when I have clicked the button.
At this moment both spin if I click on it.

```js
$(function() {

  var x = 0;

  $('button').click(function() {
    x += 90;
    $('.cubeMain').each(function(index) {
      $(this).delay(500 * index).css(
        'transform', 'rotateY(' + x + 'deg)');
    });
  });
});
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lacika1981/r2nuh5z3/ this is on JSFiddle

Comment: What do you mean by Each after each? Start rotation of 2nd after 1st div has completed rotation

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please actually read the preceding link and make sure that the code you post **in your question** is **minimal** (only bare minimum of code necessary to reproduce), **complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **verifiable** (we can reproduce the issue using only the code in your question). Without a proper MCVE **in your question**, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: post your html, please

Comment: yes I want to make the other one start to spin after 500ms. here is the code on jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lacika1981/r2nuh5z3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my assumption and your code, I believe you want to delay the css applied to div in loop.

`delay()` works with the animation (fx) `queue`. Changing a css property does not work via that mechanism, and thus is not affected by the delay directive.

There is a workaround for the same. Update your code to following

```
$(function () {

    var x = 0;

    $('button').click(function () {
        x += 90;
        $('.cubeMain').each(function (index) {           
            $(this).delay(500 * index).queue(function (next) { 
                $(this).css('transform', 'rotateY(' + x + 'deg)'); 
                next(); 
            });
       }); 
    });
});
```

For reference - http://jsfiddle.net/r2nuh5z3/1/

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted to do.

Comment: Great it worked for you :)

Comment: Cool.  CSS sure has come a long way.  I'll stick to my vanilla CSS and continue to master jQuery and JavaScript.